# MySQL CurDate() format to use MySQL EVENT for deleting (cleaning table) data after a day?

Tags: mysql, sql, events

I have a MySQL table named `registered` where one of my rows named `time` is of type `timestamp` and I wanted to add an `EVENT` where all the entries in this table are deleted if they are older than one day. I have this so far...

```
CREATE EVENT delete_registration_data
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
DELETE FROM `registered` where time < DATE_SUB(CurDate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

What I noticed however is that the `timestamp` datatype is made up of the `CURDATE()` and `CURTIME()` e.g. [2008-11-11 12:45:34](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp). Would this cause a problem for the `EVENT` handler to delete from the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE EVENT delete_registration_data
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
DELETE FROM `registered` where date(time) < DATE_SUB(CurDate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: The `date(time)` call makes sure only the date component is used?